# How does ASP.NET Core Identity ensure username is unique under concurrent conditions？

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I know ASP.NET Core Identity uses `UserValidator` to ensure the username is unique:

```cs
private async Task<List<IdentityError>?> ValidateUserName(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
{
    List<IdentityError>? errors = null;

    var userName = await manager.GetUserNameAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
    {
        errors ??= new List<IdentityError>();
        errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters) &&
            userName.Any(c => !manager.Options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters.Contains(c)))
    {
        errors ??= new List<IdentityError>();
        errors.Add(Describer.InvalidUserName(userName));
    }
    else
    {
        var owner = await manager.FindByNameAsync(userName).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (owner != null &&
            !string.Equals(await manager.GetUserIdAsync(owner).ConfigureAwait(false), await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false)))
        {
            errors ??= new List<IdentityError>();
            errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateUserName(userName));
        }
    }

    return errors;
}
```

If multiple requests come in at the same time, how does ASP.NET Core Identity handle synchronization?

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't (because it doesn't start a `TRANSACTION` to secure a table-lock between page-loads). In practice, however, two users selecting the same name at the same time never happens.

Comment: ...but assuming the DB being used for storage has a `UNIQUE` index over `UserName` then that's fine: because it still means that only 1 user will be able to actually `INSERT` with that username, and that means they get that username - while the other user will get an index-violation-error (or a friendly error-message).

Comment: So it is by design? @Dai

Comment: You can just look at the code, there is no concurrency checking for usernames https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs

Comment: Most likely handled by a **unique constraint** on the `AspNetUsers` table - column `UserName` ??

Comment: There is no unique constraint on column UserName. Need to create it by myself.@marc_s

Comment: The unique constraint is on `NormalizedUserName` when using the EF Core stores: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/8.0/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityUserContext.cs#L170.